# SVG in IE 9, will it be possible?

Tags: html

will IE 9 handle SVG drawing ?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/html5-hardware-accelerated-first-ie9-platform-preview-available-for-developers)

> IE9 is the first browser to provide fully hardware-accelerated SVG support.

Comment: And the last browser to finally come around and support it if/when it comes out next year. SVG has been around only about 10 years. It's about time.

Comment: Yes, they're late. But at least they're headed in the right direction.